# Regex to allow all types of numbers

Tags: jquery, regex, expression

I just want a field to allow ALL types of numbers: whole, decimal, negative... and all combinations of said types. No commas necessary.

This is the closest I've gotten in about 3 days of fighting with it:

```
/^[\.\-\d]*?$[1-9][\.\-\d]*?$/
```

This does not allow whole numbers! I don't undestand what is wrong, can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: If you want help for regexes, you can download this little tool, it's very simple and has helped me a lot in the past. BTW: Regex'es are complicated but extremely powerful

Comment: Asking for links and tutorials is out-of-scope for Stack Overflow.  Also, your question was mostly a rant, and I've tried to turn it into something a little more constructive and concise.

Comment: I understand the learning curve for this starts steep. It's a uniquely condensed language. Here, does anyone of these in the page fit the need? http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: tool? Gimmie please. :)

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much LittleBobbyTables. Without a doubt the most helpful response! Glad you took the time to explain ... anything for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/
```

Explanation:

```
^       # start of string anchor
-?      # match a '-', optional
\d*     # match zero or more digits
\.?     # match a '.', optional
\d+     # match one or more digits
$       # end of string anchor
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
string="some text with the number -123456.789 in it";
alert(string.replace(/[^-\d+.]/g,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/
```

Note that this will match "6.", "+5.3", "4" but not "4.4.0"

This is similar to F.J answer, but allow a positively signed input and allows the the number end in a dot ".".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for decimal numbers:

```
/^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

To break it down:

- From the start of the string...
- Optionally match a minus sign
- Either:

  - Match up to three digits
  - Optionally, match any number of (comma followed by three digits) [thousands separators]
- Or:

  - Match any number of digits [without thousands separators]
- Optionally match a decimal point followed by any number of digits.
- Check you've reached the end of the string.